# How do you create a variable that you can add numbers on to?

Tags: javascript

How do you create a variable that you can add multiple numbers on to?

For example,

```
let x = 0
let x = +1
console.log(x)
```

and I would like it to console log 1

Answer (score 2):

use **+=** operator or **x = x + number**

```js
let x = 0
x += 1
console.log(x)
x += 4
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let x = 0;
x += 1;
console.log(x);
```

or this:

```
let x = 0;
x++;
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already declared a variable you don't need to declare it again. Once you have already declared the variable as `var`, `const`, `let` you don't need to. redeclare that variable when you are setting a new value. You have to use that variable without again declaring it as `var`, `const`, `let`. So to solve your problem you have to try.

```js
let x = 0;
console.log(x); // This will return 0

x += 1
console.log(x); // This will return 1
```